# How to set super privilege in mysql databse

Tags: mysql

Here is query to create a view

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`serve3_user465`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `constantcontact_customers_agents` AS select `customers`.`CustomerID` AS `CustomerID`,`customers`.`AgentID` AS `AgentID`,`customers`.`AccountType` AS `CustomerAccountType`,`customers`.`FirstName` AS `CustomerFirstName`,`customers`.`LastName` AS `CustomerLastName`,`customers`.`Address` AS `CustomerAddress`,`customers`.`City` AS `CustomerCity`,`customers`.`State` AS `CustomerState`,`customers`.`Zip` AS `CustomerZip`,`customers`.`Phone` AS `CustomerPhone`,`customers`.`Cell` AS `CustomerCell`,`customers`.`Fax` AS `CustomerFax`,`customers`.`Email` AS `CustomerEmail`,`customers`.`Dob` AS `CustomerDob`,`agents`.`FirstName` AS `AgentFirstName`,`agents`.`LastName` AS `AgentLastName`,`agents`.`CompanyName` AS `AgentCompanyName`,`agents`.`ApiUsername` AS `ApiUsername`,`agents`.`ApiPassword` AS `ApiPassword` from (`customers` join `agents` on((`customers`.`AgentID` = `agents`.`AgentID`))) where ((`agents`.`ApiUsern[...]

MySQL said: Documentation
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to login as a different user (one that has the '`super`' privilege),or assign the `super` privilege to your user

Connect to the DB with a user that has the `GRANT` privilege and run:

```
GRANT super ON *.* to 'your_user'@'%';
```

You may want to check on the security implications of assigning the super privilege first though

[GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html)

Comment: #1045 - Access denied for user 'dev-1'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: Normally that means that your 'username'@'host' or the password is incorrect. Have you ever logged in with that username/password? You will need to find a valid user, log in with them, and check the `mysql.user` table.

Comment: If it is the `GRANT` statement that is failing, it is probably because you're current user doesn't have the `GRANT_PRIV` assigned. Run `select user(), current_user();` to confirm which user you are logged in as, and then `SELECT user,host,grant_priv from mysql.user where grant_priv = 'Y';` If you are not logged in with a user on that list you wont be able to GRANT the `super_priv`.